# Build tests depending on program sources

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool

I want to build tests for a `foo` program. My root `Makefile.am` looks like:

```
SUBDIRS = src tests
```

Makefile.am from `src` contains:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_CXXFLAGS = # a lot of $(XXX_CFLAGS)
foo_LDADD = # a lot of $(XXX_LIBS)
foo_SOURCES = # a lot of source files
```

Makefile.am from `tests` contains:

```
check_PROGRAMS = footesta footestb
TESTS = footesta footestb
footesta_SOURCES = footesta.cpp
footestb_SOURCES = footestb.cpp
```

These tests depend on `foo` symbols and I consider to create a convenience library by using some `foo_LIBADD = libfoo.la` on top and place `noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la` in `Makefile.am`'s `src`. Am I on the right way to solve this?

Comment: Why, why, why autotools? Think about the children!

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - because he doesn't want to reinvent the wheel, that `cmake` is (slowly) reinventing?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way, but I would suggest you a couple of different options too.

First of all, I'd suggest you to look into using [non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) so that instead of three `Makefile.am` you only have one to keep up to date, and reduces the nasty factor of autotools.

In particular, using the convenience library method across separate `Makefile.am` makes dependency tracking terribly complicated, which means that you may or may not re-run the tests properly if you're changing, say, a header file. The dependency tracking is done properly when using a single, non-recursive, `Makefile.am`.

The other option, again using a non-recursive build system, is to declare variables with group of sources, so that you would have

```
SELF_CONTAINED_SRCS = foo.h foo1.c foo2.c foo3.c
foo_SOURCES = $(SELF_CONTAINED_SRCS) main.c other.c

footest_SOURCES = footesta.c $(SELF_CONTAINED_SRCS)
```

this avoids the intra-step of running the archiver to generate the `.a` file and then for the linker to unpack it, while still sharing the compiled sources (as long as you don't use per-target `CFLAGS`).

If you plan on using per-target `CFLAGS` (say you want to have test-specific code in `foo3.c`), then you will not be able to share the compiled object files between the two targets, but that is also possible when using the variable-expansion, and not possible with the convenience library, which is why that's actually my preferred option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the non-recursive way, as simplifies the maintenance process a lot.